# How to get Spotify UserId?

Tags: spotify, userid, spotify-app

We are currently working on a `spotify` app but we don't know how to get `the unique userId`
Does anyone know how to get it ?

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22134072/9970) says that Spotify is intentionally hiding it from you.  They've provided you with the `identifier` field to give you a key to identify a user using your app.